# BFG 680i beep codes

Tags: motherboard

I have a BFG 680i mobo with a core 2 quad q6600 cpu. Working fine for over a year, now when i boot it it gives me a long beep and two short beeps. This occurs at led code 26, indicating a clock issue?  The manual has no beep code detail.

Does anyone have a beep code reference for the 680i chipset motherboard series?

Edit: [this site](http://www.pchell.com/hardware/beepcodes.shtml) indicates a display adapter problem, which makes sense as there is no video. However, if I turn it off for a few hours, it boots fine and has video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this mobo has been eating video cards, but isn't willing to boot without one.  I just need to avoid letting it shutdown/reboot.

Comment: Try checking/replacing your power supply. It may be defective or marginal/out-of-spec for your setup, even if the paper specs seem to be OK.

Comment: Funny, I unplugged the aux power port on the mobo and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't, but, as one who has exercised BFG's lifetime warranty, I'd say "call 'em."  You'll get a live human, located in the US, that actually knows what they're talking about.

At least, that's been my experience.  YMMV.